# Logging WCF Message Information After Exception in Encoder

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

We have a WCF client/server application written in C# (.NET Framework 2.0).  Part of our WCF stack is the GZipMessageEncoder.  Sometimes, a report in our application requests a lot of data.  This causes an error in the GZipMessageEncoder:

```
System.InsufficientMemoryException: Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 268435456 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low.
---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
    at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.AllocateByteArray(Int32 size) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.AllocateByteArray(Int32 size)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManager.PooledBufferManager.TakeBuffer(Int32 bufferSize)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputStream.Init(Int32 initialSize, Int32 maxSizeQuota, Int32 effectiveMaxSize, BufferManager bufferManager)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncoderFactory.BinaryMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
    at profdata.com.Library.GZipMessageEncoderFactory.GZipMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
```

I've changed the GZipMessageEncoder to log this message to the Windows event log so support staff can track when the error occurs:

> The web service did not have enough memory to respond to a request. 
>   The connection will be closed, and the client may receive the error
>   "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

I would like to include the report name and parameters in the event log message.  Unfortunately, I don't have enough information in the WCF Message class itself to determine what the error was.  The request information is actually a small DataSet in the body that contains the report name and parameters.

I was thinking it would be nice if I could attach some non-serialized data to the Message.  In the GZipMessageEncoder, when this error occurs, I could peel off this data and log the report name and parameters.

How can I log information from a message body from inside a WCF encoder?  Would I need to keep a report information object in thread-local storage instead?  Or a static dictionary of Message-to-report information objects?